# What is the job title of these municipal officers?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

In some countries, specially in Asia, some vendors spread their stuff for sale on the ground (upper picture), and thereby cause trouble for the pedestrians comeing and going. For preventing this, there are some officers whose job is preventing those vendors from selling their stuff in the sidewalks!

Is there any special word or phrase for referring to those **officers whose task is to alleviate street congestion"?* (lower picture)

[image]

[image]

Comment: as I know its -  Municipal Officers  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Municipality)

Comment: Thanks dear @alpa! :) Good! , but I 'm looking for a word or phrase for a subdivision of those officers whose job is only what I described before.

Comment: Municipal Corporations are in to various spheres - including "property management" like property santitation,taxation,usage etc. They usually have officers to look after hygeine and property usage for assigned areas. And as such Municipal Administrators are the ones you could check with.

Comment: Yes, @alpa! exactly! But I don't know how to call the exact department (?) for these officers( preventing street congestion)

Comment: Ideally you may want to check with "encroachment" and/or "enforcement" division to update and request action for people causing incovinience and encroaching  pedestrian rights. But I might suggest humanitarian view and let them continue earning their livelihood and not further stomp them because you could

Comment: No dear alpa! I don't want to prevent them from earning money! I feel pity for them,too! Actually a friend who is learning English , asked  me this question! But I didn't know the answer!:) so I put forward it here!:)

Comment: Can I say" municipal officers from enforcement division"? , suppose that I have an English oral exam and I have to describe the lower picture! :)

Comment: as one of the answers notes, the exact term will depend on whether they are enforcing a hygiene ordinance against blocking sidewalks, or enforcing a business ordinance requiring vendors to have permits. then you can call **hygiene inspectors** or **commerce compliance officers**, something along those lines. What are they called in Bahasa, or whatever the local language is?

Comment: @jlovegren, Thanks for your comment. In Persian well call them "مأموران رفع سد معبر" (ma'mouran e  raf'e sadde ma'bar).

Comment: @Soudabeh so why not just use a semi-literal translation, like **sidewalk inspectors** or **roadside hygiene officers**? You can also clarify in your essay with something like "(a special unit of the XXX municipal government)"

Comment: @jlovegren, very good suggestions, I'll use them. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

In the US such activities are generally regulated by city or municipal ordinances and often enforced by **ordinance enforcement officers** or just **ordinance officers**. These officers may deal with parking, zoning, codes and so on. Larger cities will have specialists for each type of orninance, but in smaller ones a single officer does duty in multiple areas.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, It depends on whether the vendors' "stuffs" (sic)* includes **food**. If it does, the enforcement is more likely to be for a violation of health-related licensing requirements, so it would be done by (County) Health Department **inspectors**, who would not just tell them to move out of the way, but would force them to shut down operations until they could get the proper **permit(s)**.

If the selling is actually blocking traffic, **police officers** would be called to disperse the street merchants.  This might be performed by the **traffic enforcement division** of the police department—the same people who would ticket illegally parked cars.

*"stuff" is generally a non-count noun

Comment: Thanks a lot ! @Brian Hitchcock! +1 , in my country( Iran) the municipal officers are responsible for preventing vendors selling  stuff in the streets, so what should I use for referring  to those officers?, " municipal enforcement officers" is correct?

Comment: I have no idea. I can speak only for my country. If you are speaking of, say, Malaysia, it would be best to research Malaysia.  All I can say is that "municipal officer" is a very broad term, which is not specific to the type of enforcement you mentioned. To me, a "municipal officer" could mean anyone from a _police officer_, to a _bailiff_, to a _meter reader_, to a _park ranger_.

Answer (score 1):

Municipal Corporations are in to various spheres - including "property management" like property santitation,taxation,usage etc. They usually have officers to look after hygeine and property usage for assigned areas. And as such Municipal Administrators are the ones you could check with.

Ideally you may want to check with "encroachment" and/or "enforcement" division to update and request action for people causing incovinience and encroaching pedestrian rights. But I might suggest humanitarian view and let them continue earning their livelihood and not further stomp them because you could.

I am glad I could assist you.

Thank you!

Comment: Sure thing, Please pick one that best fits your needs. Thank you! :)